# redeclare incorrect typsescript type in 3rd party library

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I'm using winston 3.0 with the @types/winston types. These types are not yet fully compatible, and I've come across an error in the types which I don't know how to correct.

Here's my code.

**logger.ts**

```
export function middleware(): express.Handler {
    const transport = new winston.transports.Console({
        json: true,
        colorize: true,
        stringify: getStringify()
    });
    const loggerOptions: expressWinston.LoggerOptionsWithTransports = {
        transports: [transport],
        meta: true,
        msg: "HTTP {{req.method}} {{req.url}}", 
        expressFormat: true, 
        colorize: false 
    };

    return expressWinston.logger(loggerOptions);
}
```

The ts error on loggerOptions is

> Property 'writable' is missing in type 'TransportInstance'

The problem is fixed if I extend the TransportInstance interface in @types/winston with NodeJS.WriteStream. i.e. change this:

```
interface TransportInstance extends TransportStatic, NodeJS.EventEmitter {
```

to this:

```
interface TransportInstance extends TransportStatic, NodeJS.EventEmitter, NodeJS.WriteStream {
```

But of course, I can't change that because it's a 3rd party dependancy and the declaration is in node_modules. So how do I redeclare an interface which I've imported as an npm dependency?

I've started looking into [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html):

**logger.d.ts**

```
import * as winston from "winston";

export namespace winston {
    export interface TransportInstance
        extends winston.TransportInstance,
            NodeJS.WriteStream {}
}
```

But this doesn't have any impact. I'm not sure how to import this interface into logger.js instead of the one that comes in when I import the winston library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).  This works for me:

```
declare module "winston" {
    interface TransportInstance extends NodeJS.WriteStream {}
}
```

Comment: Hmm. No, but I may be doing it wrong. I've added your code to logger.d.ts. My function using TransportInstance is in logger.ts. I've not explicitly imported anything into logger.ts. Should I? I've also tried adding your code directly into logger.ts, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: I tested and it is working for me without the namespace, though I don't really understand what is going on here.  Edited the answer.