# wrap type definition of a 3rd library function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I use Typescript to enforce immutability. Most libraries don't type their exported functions parameters as `Readonly` (or `DeepReadonly`) even if they don't mutate them. This causes a common issue since a `ReadonlyArray` is not assignable as an `Array`.
We can redefine the function using module augmentation, as explained [in this SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734248/redeclare-incorrect-typsescript-type-in-3rd-party-library). But how can we wrap existing type definition, so we use current definition, but define all params as `DeepReadonly`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this generic:

```js
export type DeepReadonlyObject<A> = { readonly [K in keyof A]: DeepReadonlyObject<A[K]> };
```

It's map all attributes into `readonly` and all values to `DeepReadonlyObject` values recursively.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAixhgErAIYAmEAdgDaIDyARgFbADGMAPAIIB8cAvHAN5xT4iZRHADaAaTgBLYnADWwRBABmcFgF0AXOkw5BJctTqNWE9RwC%20AbgBQSFHGxcdWXIQOVaDZnwWJtAM4wUDIA5gA08ooAjNq%20itpUEBCk%20LIWcBZstjagkLBwALYQBACuqXAAsiW8NnD1cHnQ8PQkQXB4XAAsAEx1FjZ2yKjY0c4YrvrCRt5M9sAqVSVsQA)

-------------Edited---------------

You can overwrite imported types by `declare module "Lib" {` syntax. However in module definition we can not use iterations. So I'm afraid you have to declare each key by hand e.g.

```js
module "Lib" { 
    export const value = { key: 42 };
    export const value1 = { key: 42 };
}

declare module "Lib" {
    export type value = DeepReadonlyObject<typeof Lib.value>;
}
```

Unfortunately each key have to placed in declared module.

Comment: I'm aware of DeepReadonly. The challenge here is to wrap/augment the type of a 3rd library type definition.